# 403 forbidden linkedin and InsufficientPermissionException

Tags: java, spring, linkedin-api, http-status-code-403, spring-social

I have configure LinkedIn API with app_key and Secret Value and also registered with vetted API , I have also positive reply from LinkedIn Team.

I am trying to search people by first name and last Name in Spring Social In view Side my simple snippet code look like

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/auth/linkedin"/>">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" /> <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri"
        value="http://localhost:8080/easy-spring-social-example/user/register">

        <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="r_emailaddress,r_contactinfo,r_network,r_fullprofile" />

        <button class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
            <spring:message code="label.linkedin.sign.in.button" />
        </button>
</form>
```

here action tag `'/auth/linkedin'` for that I have used `ConnectController` and also I have putted scope in hidden with value `r_fullprofile`

and at coding side my simple snippet code look like

```
Connection connection = ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request);

    if (connection != null) {

        LinkedIn linkedIn = (LinkedIn) connection.getApi();
        System.out.println("Profile Id :-" + linkedIn.profileOperations().getProfileId());

        String firstName = "lotiya";
        String lastName = "hardik";

        SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
        searchParameters.setFirstName(firstName);
        searchParameters.setLastName(lastName);
        LinkedInProfiles profiles = linkedIn.profileOperations().search(searchParameters);

        System.out.println("Profile Found :" + profiles.getCount());
    }
```

here first request(`WebRequest`) come from social provider (`LinkedIn`) with log in successfully and then Initialize LinkedIn Object from API after complete this process try to fetch people by first name and last name using `searchParameters` in `profileOperation` Interface.

I traced the code line by line one thing is that

`linkedIn.profileOperations().search(searchParameters)` this code return

```
org.springframework.social.InsufficientPermissionException
```

at this point return 403 status as forbidden request Error....